# Trying to create a linked list for the first time

Tags: c++, linked-list

**First i would like to say i'm sorry, pretty sure the problem will be pretty basic,
but it's the first time i'm trying to create a linked list.**

The problem is when i try to allocate memory and putt a new node address inside the "nodeHead" i get an error saying:

> > error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'MatchmakingAgency::Node *' to 'Node *'
> >
> > IntelliSense: a value of type "MatchmakingAgency::Node *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Node *"

Here are the files:

> **MatchmakingAgency.h - The database class**

```
class Node;

#include "Client.h"
#ifndef _MatchmakingAgency_H_
#define _MatchmakingAgency_H_

class MatchmakingAgency
{
private:
    Node* nodeHead;
    Node* nodeTail;

    //Node class
    class Node
    {
    private:
        Client* client;
        Node* next;
    public:
        Node();
        Node(Client*);
        Node(Client*,Node*);
    };
    //end of Node class

public:
    MatchmakingAgency();
    MatchmakingAgency(Client*);
    ~MatchmakingAgency();

    void printDatabase();

};

#endif
```

> **MatchmakingAgency.cpp**

```
#include "MatchmakingAgency.h"

MatchmakingAgency::MatchmakingAgency(){
    nodeHead = nodeTail = NULL;
}

MatchmakingAgency::MatchmakingAgency(Client* data){
    nodeHead = new Node(data);
}

MatchmakingAgency::~MatchmakingAgency(){
}
```

> **Node.cpp**

```
#include "MatchmakingAgency.h"

MatchmakingAgency::Node::Node(){
    next = NULL;
}

MatchmakingAgency::Node::Node(Client* data){
    client = data;
    next = NULL;
}

MatchmakingAgency::Node::Node(Client* data,Node* nextnode){
    client = data;
    next = nextnode;
}
```

Hope you could help me with it,
and please don't be mad ;)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, think about what the error message *means*. Do you have an idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the forward declaration:

```
class Node;
```

into class `MatchmakingAgency` in `MatchmakingAgency.h` file from the top.

```
//class Node; << remove this

#include "Client.h"
#ifndef _MatchmakingAgency_H_
#define _MatchmakingAgency_H_

class MatchmakingAgency
{
private:
    class Node; // << move here
    Node* nodeHead;
```

Comment: That worked, Thanks!

Can you explain why and how did it fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to be consistent in using fully qualified names:

```
MatchmakingAgency::Node::Node(Client* data,MatchmakingAgency::Node* nextnode){
    client = data;
    next = nextnode;
}
```